# How to print multiple attrributes from a hashMap that is a property inside a toString override

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and writing code to check my understanding.  I'm trying to use a toString override to print the values of a hashMap that is a  property of a class.  I can't get it to work.  Instead I get output like "kotlin.Unit() -> kotlin.Unit".  Also, I don't understand why the values of the hashMap ARE printing out before the toString output.  I don't know where that output is coming from.  Please help me. Thanks.  Below is my code and the output I'm getting.
Code:

```
package ch07.ExpandoObject

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport
import kotlin.properties.Delegates
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty


class Person(

    val name: String = "",
    age: Int? = null,
    var isMarried: Boolean? = null  ,_attributes: kotlin.collections.HashMap<String,String>? = hashMapOf<String, String>()
)
    :PropertyChangeAware()
{
    var _attributes : kotlin.collections.HashMap<String,String>? = hashMapOf<String, String>()
    fun setAttribute(attrName: String, value: String) {
        _attributes!!.set(attrName, value)
        _attributes!!.set("name", this.name)
    }


    override fun toString() = "Person(name=\"${name?:""}\", age=${age?:99999}, isMarried=$isMarried) " +
            "${_attributes?.get("name")} " + "$name " +
            this._attributes!!.forEach { (attrName, value) -> println("$attrName = $value") } +
            {
                for ((attrName, value) in this._attributes!!) {
                    println("attribute $attrName = ${this._attributes!![attrName]}")
                }

            }

    val _age = ObservableProperty(propName = "age", propValue = age, changeSupport = changeSupport)

    private val observer = {
            prop: KProperty<*>, oldValue: Int, newValue: Int ->
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange(prop.name, oldValue, newValue)
    }

    var age: Int by Delegates.observable(initialValue = age?:99999,onChange = observer)



}

class ObservableProperty(val propName: String,
                         var propValue: Int?, val changeSupport: PropertyChangeSupport
) {
    fun getValue(): Int? = propValue

    fun setValue( newValue: Int) {
        val oldValue = propValue
        propValue = newValue
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propName, oldValue, newValue)
    }
}

open class PropertyChangeAware {
    val changeSupport = PropertyChangeSupport(this)

    fun addPropertyChangeListener(listener: PropertyChangeListener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener)
    }

    fun removePropertyChangeListener(listener: PropertyChangeListener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener)
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person("Bob", 89, isMarried = false)
    val data = mapOf("lastname" to "Jones", "company" to "JetBrains")
    for ((attrName, value) in data)
        p.setAttribute(attrName, value)
    println(p)

}
```

Here is the current output:

```
name = Bob
company = JetBrains
lastname = Jones
Person(name="Bob", age=89, isMarried=false) Bob Bob kotlin.Unit() -> kotlin.Unit
```

Thanks, again, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `print()` or `println()` functions inside `toString()` because they output their arguments to the standard output **immediately** instead of appending them to the string returned to the caller.

Let's examine the output `kotlin.Unit() -> kotlin.Unit` you're getting. It consists of two parts:

- `kotlin.Unit` is the string representation of `attributes!!.forEach { ... }` expression. `forEach` function returns without value, and in Kotlin it's expressed by returning the [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions) object value. Its string representation is appended to the string you're returning.
- the second part, `() -> kotlin.Unit`, is also the string representation of the [lambda function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) expression `{ for((attrName, value) in ...) }`. This function takes no parameters, and returns without value, which means that its type is `() -> Unit`. Note that in Kotlin the block `{ ... }` declares a local lambda function. If you instead want to run the code inside of that block, use the `run` function: `run { ... }`

The goal of `toString` function is to *build the string representation* of an object. And for that you can use [`buildString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html) function:

```
  override fun toString() = buildString {
    append("Person(name=\"${name?:""}\", age=${age?:99999}, isMarried=$isMarried) ")
    append("${_attributes?.get("name")} ").append("$name ")
    this._attributes!!.forEach { (attrName, value) -> append("$attrName = $value") }
    for ((attrName, value) in this._attributes!!) {
      append("attribute $attrName = ${this._attributes!![attrName]}")
    }
  }
```

This function creates a `StringBuilder` and passes it as [a receiver to its functional argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), where you call `append` or `appendln` on that receiver. Then `buildString` converts that string builder to a string and returns it.

Comment: I got it working like this:

    override fun toString() = buildString{
        append("Person(name=\"${name ?: ""}\", age=${age ?: 99999}, isMarried=$isMarried) \n")
                //"${_attributes?.get("name")} " + "$name " +
       // this._attributes!!.forEach ( (attrName, value) -> append("$attrName = $value")
        for ((attrName, value) in _attributes!!) {
            append("attribute $attrName = ${_attributes!![attrName]}\n")

                }
    }

Thanks, so much, for your help and explanation.  I couldn't have done it without you.